# Notation in the Liouville-von Neumann equation $ i\hbar\frac{dI}{dt} = i\hbar\frac{\partial I}{\partial t} + [I, H] $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, density-operator, time-evolution

The Liouville-von Neumannn equation is defined by
$$
i\hbar\frac{dI}{dt} = i\hbar\frac{\partial I}{\partial t} + [I, H]
$$
where $I$ is any operator and $H$ is the Hamiltonian. I assume that the left-hand side of the equation is a total derivative of $I$ while the right hand side involves a partial derivative of $I$. How is the total derivative of an operator defined in the context of quantum mechanics? Oftentimes, the equation is useful when $\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$; is the relationship derived from the Schrödinger equation?

Comment: Are you sure you're citing the von Neumann equation? Compare e.g. with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Liouville-von Neumann equation can be directly derived from Heisenberg picture?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112984/)