# Difference between $dM/dt $ and $\partial M/\partial t$

Tags: time, conservation-laws, notation, differentiation

$\frac{dM}{dt} = 0$ represents a constant of motion $M.$ Why not $\frac{\partial M}{\partial t}$ represent a constant of motion $M$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between implicit and explicit time dependence e.g. $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{d \rho} {dt}$?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/)

Comment: What is M? What is the physical situation? Without that info, it's hard to help. (But see the link in the comment above.)

Comment: Can you please tell how M will matter? Some examples , if you can give?

Comment: I'm taking M, for example say a function of x,v and t. i.e. M=M(x,v,t)

Comment: Why did dM/dt=0 represent M as a constant of motion ,and not del(M)/del(t)=0?

Comment: I,m not asking when they are equal or not

Comment: $$M = M\left( {t,{x_1},...,{x_n}} \right)$$
$$\frac{{dM}}{{dt}} = \frac{{\partial M}}{{\partial t}}\frac{{dt}}{{dt}} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{\partial M}}{{\partial {x_i}}}\frac{{d{x_i}}}{{dt}}} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{dM}{dt} = \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{x}}\frac{d{x}}{d{t}} = \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}+v\cdot\nabla{M}$ (with no assumption on what is M) . So if $v\cdot\nabla{M} \neq0$ you can have one of $\frac{dM}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}$ that is zero when the other is not.

$\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}=0$ means *stationarity* of the quantity $M$: at a given fix location in space $M$ doesn't change in time. Now, flowing particles might have their $M(x(t),t)$ changing in time, i.e. $\frac{dM}{dt} \neq 0$.

$\frac{dM}{dt} = 0$ means conservation of the quantity $M$ for the given flowing particles. Now if the flow is not stationary the value that you see at a given location x might change in time: $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}(x) \neq 0$ .