# Meaning of time derivative of an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time, differentiation, observables

Today when my professor was deriving this equation: 
$$\frac{\mathrm d\langle A\rangle}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\left[H,\,A\right]\rangle+\left\langle\frac{\partial A}{\partial t}\right\rangle,
$$
he treated the corresponding operator of the observable $A$ as if it was a function and took its time derivative and it shows up in the last term of the equation as can be seen.

What I don't get is what does it mean to take the time derivative of an operator? If the operator is a multiplicative function, then I can understand it, but suppose the operator was $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$, what does it mean to take the time derivative of a $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ operator?

Comment: It's just how you'd expect by ordinary calculus. The time derivative of $d/dx$ is just zero, but the time derivative of $t \, d/dx$ is $d/dx$.

Comment: If you want, you can think of operators as matrices, in which case the time derivative is taken by taking the time derivative of the elements of the matrix.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One comment pointed out that the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  \frac{d}{dx} = 0$. In a certain sense however $ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d}{dx} \neq 0$. I will try to explain this further.

Let's think first about kinematics. Then we have a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and some operator $A$ on it. For example the Hilbert space could be the space of square-integrable functions and $A$ the derivative, $\mathscr{H} = L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $A = \frac{d}{dx}$.

If we want to study time evolution, we have to prescribe an one-parameter group of unitaries, $U_t$. We may now ask for the orbits of operators under this group of unitaries, that is, we might be interested in

$$ A(t) := U_t^{-1} A U_t \ . $$

We might additionally study observables which we let parametrically depend on $t$; for example we may multiply an operator with a function $f(t)$. I will ignore this in the following, but it is not hard to take into account. Take a time evolution operator

$$U_t = \exp(- i H t) \ .$$

Then we may compute the time derivative of $A(t)$:

$$ \frac{d A(t)}{dt} = \frac{d }{dt} \left(e^{ i t H} A e^{-i t H}\right) =  (i H) e^{ i t H} A e^{-i t H} +  e^{ i t H} A e^{-i t H} ( - i H) = i [H,A(t)] \ .  $$

Let's consider the case of $A = \frac{d}{dx}$ in more detail, and let's choose

$$H = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \frac{1}{2} x^2 \ ,$$

which is of course the harmonic oscillator. Now we want to see what

$$A(t) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)(t)$$

is. Note that this is no longer the derivative! The connection it has to the derivative is that

$$ \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)(0) = \frac{d}{dx}  \ .$$

The equation of motion for $A$ is

$$ \frac{d A(t)}{dt} = i [ H(t), A(t)] = \frac{i}{2} \left[ x(t)^2, \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)(t) \right] \ . $$

Here i used that $H(t) = H$. In this formula we may now use that for two operators $B(t),C(t)$ that are obtained from operators $B,C$ by conjugating with an unitary $U_t$, it holds that

$$ [B(t),C(t)] = ([B,C])(t)  \ .$$

Hence

$$ \left[ x(t)^2, \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)(t) \right] = \left(\left[ x^2, \frac{d}{dx}\right] \right)(t) = 2 x(t) \ . $$

Playing the same game with $x(t)$, we get the set of coupled equations

$$ \frac{d \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\!(t)}{d t} = i x(t) \ , \\ 
\frac{d x(t)}{dt} =  i \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\!(t)  \ .$$

which may be easily solved to give

$$ \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\!(t) = \cos(t) \frac{d}{dx} + i \sin(t) x \, \\
   x(t) = \cos(t) x + i \sin(t) \frac{d}{dx} \ . $$

Comment: Why is (d/dx)(0)=d/dx and not (d/dx)(1)=d/dx?

Comment: I don't get the question... Are you saying it should be the case or that some equation says that?

Comment: I feel like it should be the case

Comment: In the way i defined it (as is usual), the relation between an operator $A$ and its time-translate $A(t)$ is $A(t) = U_t^* A U_t$, so that $A(0) = U_0^* A U_0$. You may furthermore check that $U_0$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you look carefully one is (mostly) taking derivatives of *average  values* of an observable.  These average values are certainly real functions so it makes sense to “keep track of the average $\langle A\rangle$ as a function of time” and then take the derivative of this function.

As to $\langle \partial A/\partial t\rangle$, it is possible to have an operator that is explicitly time dependent.  This may occur for instance when a potential changes explicitly with time.  In this case, it makes sense to think of the derivative of this operator, and then take the average value of this derivative.