# Expectation of partial time derivatives of $x$ in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, notation, differentiation

In [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem) we know that
$$m\frac{d\left< x\right>}{dt}=\left< p\right>+m\left<\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right>.$$
So how can I exactly calculate a specific $\left<\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right>$ in coordinate representation?

Answer (score 0):

The "partial time derivative symbol" $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}$ denotes the [explicit time derivative](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/2451). The fundamental phase space variables (such as, e.g. $\hat{x}$) don't depend explicitly on time, neither in the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) nor in [Schrödinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture).