# What does $\frac{Dv}{Dt}$ and $\frac{D\rho}{Dt}$ notion mean here?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, time, definition, differentiation, notation

Momentum conservation:
$$\rho\frac{Dv}{Dt}=\nabla\cdot\sigma+\rho g$$

Mass conservation:
$$\frac{D\rho}{Dt}+\rho\nabla\cdot v=0$$

What does $\frac{Dv}{Dt}$ and $\frac{D\rho}{Dt}$ notion mean here and how this derivatives can be re-expressed in term of partial derivatives?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi Alexey Tigarev. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please only ask 1 question per post. I removed your other questions.

Comment: D/Dt is the time derivative as reckoned by an observer traveling along with the fluid at the local velocity.  That is, as reckoned from a Lagrangian frame of reference.  It is not the covariant derivative.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you have a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ of $n+1$ variables. If $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ is a differentiable curve in $\mathbb R^n$, you can compose it with $f$ to obtain a differentiable function of a single variable $h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, namely

$$h(t) = f(g(t),t)$$

The derivative of $h$ can be expressed in terms of the differential of both $f$ and $g$ by using the chain rule, viz.

$$\frac{\text dh}{\text dt} = \nabla_{\mathbf x}f\cdot\frac{\text dg}{\text dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.$$

When $g$ represents the flow over time of physical points, e.g., the points of some *material* evolving in time, its derivative is a velocity field $\mathbf v$ and it is customary to use the notation of the OP to denote the variation of $f$ over time along the flow. This is known as the *material derivative*. Indeed, it is just a total derivative with respect to the "time" variable $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$D$ stands for covariant derivative. The equation is the covariant form of the continuity equation.

Comment: Also known as the substantial or material derivative.

Comment: Can it be re-expressed in terms of partial derivatives by x, y, t ?

Answer (score -1):

The total derivative. Essentially if you have a multi-variable function dependent on position coordinates and also say a scalar like time, then it's total Derivative is the sum of the partials of the functions with the position coordinate plus the partials of the function with time (i.e: the scalar coordinates)