# Does time-independence of potential energy imply time-independence of the Hamiltonian in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, potential-energy, time, hamiltonian

Consider a quantum mechanical system for a particle with Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+\hat{V}$ where $\hat{V}$ is the potential energy operator. and now let us assume that $\hat{V}$ is time-independent. Does it follow that $\hat{H}$ is time-independent?

In particular, I am interested in the case of potential wells/potential barriers/$\delta$ potentials where this seems to be used in every treatment I have found so far.

---

**My thoughts:** In general, since wavefunctions can be dependent of time, so can $\hat{p}$ by its very definition and hence $\hat{H}$ can be time-dependent. However, I wonder if $\hat{V}$ being time-independent already yields the restriction that wavefunctions do not depend on time and hence $\hat{p}$ also doesn't. This seems like a sort of circular reasoning and I'm not sure how to continue here.

Comment: $\hat{p}$ is an operator. It can act on wavefunctions, but why would it vary with time just because wavefunctions can vary with time? I don't get your train of thought here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think that "time-independence" of an operator $\hat{T}$ means $\hat{T}\psi(x,t)=\hat{T}\psi(x,\tilde{t})$ for all times $t$ and $\tilde{t}$. Or am I confusing things?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9122/2451

Comment: No, that's not what time-independence means. We usually just mean that the operator does not explicitly depend on time.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Got it, thanks! So if my understanding is correct, $\hat{H}$ in the above is really time-independent.

Comment: @ACuriousMind isnt this purely mathematical, shows no effort from OP, and should be made [closed], yet still this doesn't get closed but a effort post does get closed :/

Comment: @Aditya This question is *not* purely mathematical, since what constitutes a time-dependent operator is an important physical question. If you have a problem with **your** question being closed, it would be more productive to raise the issue on the [meta board](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com) rather than in comments to completely unrelated questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it would be helpful to take a more abstract view for a moment.

A linear operator $\hat A$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ is a linear map from $\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathcal H$.  If $\mathcal H=L^2(\mathbb R)$, then elements of the Hilbert space essentially consist of square-integrable functions of one real variable, which we usually interpret as the position of a particle on a line.

Examples of such operators might include $\hat X$ or $\hat P$, which act on suitable vectors $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ to produce other vectors
$$\big(\hat Xf\big)(x) = x f(x)$$
$$\big(\hat Pf\big)(x) = -i\hbar f'(x)$$

Put differently, an operator is just a rule for taking a square-integrable function and spitting out another square-integrable function.

---

In contrast, consider the **family** of operators $\hat Q(t)$ which eat vectors $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and spit out

$$\big(\hat Q(t) f\big) (x) = (x+t^2) f(x)$$

Notice that for each $t$, $\hat Q(t)$ is a **different operator**.  $\hat Q(0)$ is just $\hat X$, while $\hat Q(1)$ multiplies the wavefunction by $(x+1)$, and $\hat Q(-17)$ multiplies the wavefunction by $(x+289)$, and so on. We typically call $\hat Q$ a *time-dependent operator*, which is a different way of saying that the rule by which vectors are mapped to other vectors is different for each value of $t$.

---

Having made this distinction, the answer to your question becomes clear.  $\hat X$, which encodes the rule "multiply the wavefunction by $x$," and $\hat P$, which encodes the rule "differentiate the wavefunction and multiply by $-i\hbar$," are both time-independent because those rules don't change with time.  Similarly, if the potential energy operator is given by some $V(\hat X)$ which encodes the rule "multiply the wavefunction by $V(x)$", then it too is a time-independent operator.

In contrast, the operator (or alternatively, the *family* of operators) $U(\hat X,t)$ which encodes the rule "multiply the wavefunction by $x+\sin(t)$" is time-**dependent** because the rule is different for different values of $t$; for instance, $U(\hat X,0)$ encodes the rule "multiply the wavefunction by $x$" while $U(\hat X,\pi/2)$ encodes the rule "multiply the wavefunction by $x+1$".